# Post-WTC 2017 data get together, Chicago

Tags: discussion

Any interested in an informal get-together in Chicago after WTC 2017 - to discuss data, cloud, commercial applications and related?

I'll be presenting a talk at WTC: "Patterns in Functional Data Analysis" and my colleague will also present a more application-oriented talk based on our work in FinTech.

We're particularly interested in commercial applications, cloud-based workflows and client-facing UIs, using WL.

By informal we mean no fixed agenda, but we're interested in show-and-tell, sharing skills and experiences and possibly recruitment.

Space is limited, likely to 10 people or less, so in case there's more demand will have to limit or arrange skype session.

Location: Airbnb in Ukranian Village, near downtown Chi.

When: 1 or 2 days between Oct 21-24.

Treats: pizza and wine/beer

Comment: It sounds like a great idea but I will be traveling post conference. As the conference starts on a Tuesday perhaps suggesting pre-WTC on the Monday would be better. I for one arrive a day early to account for potential travel disruptions.